# How large is the blender "world"?

Tags: world

Sorry for the "newbie" question.

When I create an object on the "stage", especially a large object, if I push it far into the back ground, it starts to disappear.  If I push far enough it seems to disappear behind some invisible wall.

Is there a limit to how far the horizon is in Blender? Can that be changed somewhere in settings?  I don't see any obvious settings that effect that.

Thanks for your help!

RonK95

Comment: Search for "Clipping".

Comment: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26955/what-is-the-max-size-of-a-scene-in-blender

Comment: Also read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93503/maximum-object-size-for-blender