# Artifacts when rendering irregular mesh in Cycles (black lines)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry, artifacts

when I render with Cycles any mesh (specially planes) with a bit of irregular shape (by using previously, for example, a displacement map) some black lines appear on it. Those black lines are not random, they are always matching the edges of the geometry:

[image: different representations of the same object]

.

I tried switching between Smooth and Flat shading, changing material, but it does not affect. I have to subdivide it many times to get smaller lines visible, but that is not a solution. Those artifacts only appear in non-planar faces. You can see another example at this render:

[image]
Notice the brick texture is completely covered in black lines. The 3D model it's a simple subdivided plane and a displacement modifier applied over it.

Any idea? It seems that when the angle between two faces reach some point the edge is rendered in black color. Did I forget something to avoid this annoying thing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This may be just a numerical issue, related to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93503/maximum-object-size-for-blender/) and already [reported as a bug](https://developer.blender.org/T43835). Scaling down your object might solve the problem.

Comment: Great! scaling the objects that suffer this effect might mitigate or accentuate the artifacts. Instead of scaling my scene, I chose to translate all the objects to a position closer to the (0,0,0) coordinates and the issue dissapeared as well. Thank you very much quiliup, didn't know this was a bug.